# Creating pagerefs referring to article version in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, page-numbering

Is there any existing way to include references to page numbers in the supporting material in a beamer presentation?

Assume that I have two files, one for generating the handout in `article` class, and one for the presentation which use a shared input file (along the lines suggested on page 206 of the `beamer` documentation). Assume further that the handout includes extensive source code/a complete derivation of a proof/a complete list of example sentences/a long table or similar in the handout which the audience will have in front of them. My idea would be to define a command `\hopageref{label}` that digs for the page number of `label` in the corresponding handout (i.e. `article`) file's `.aux` file, which would be used something like this:

```
\mode<article>{\label{longtable}
    % include long table here
    }
\mode<presentation>{(Details on page \hopageref{longtable})}
```

(this workflow would require to compile the handout before the presentation to assure correct page numbers, but that seems like an acceptable limitation.)

Unfortunately, defining such a command exceeds my coding skills, but maybe something similar already exists?

Comment: The package `xr` allows this, but obviously you have to use a different filename for the article and the presentation, or the `.aux` file would be overwritten. At least you have to rename the `.aux` file you get after the final typesetting in article mode.

Comment: I'm aware that I'll need two `aux` files. I'm thinking about having a shared content file and two master files which refer to it as input. So the `xr` package seems like a perfect solution. Feel free to make this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xr` package, or maybe `zref-xr` for more powerful features, is the tool you're looking for.

However, you have to use different names for your files, say

```
jakob-art.tex
```

and

```
jakob-pres.tex
```

for the article mode and presentation mode versions respectively. Both can input a common file `jakob.tex`, of course. In the presentation version you'll add

```
\input{xr}
\externaldocument{jakob-art}
```

The labels should only appear in the article mode, of course.